# How can i get the result of an query from BigQuery in Airflow, and attach it into an email auto-send to me

Tags: google-bigquery, airflow

I want to use dynamic time `{{ macros.ds_add(ds, 0) }}`, so `pandas_gbq.read_gbq` doesn't work.

I also used the `get_pandas_df` of `BigQueryHook`, it showed `'BigQueryPandasConnector'` object has no attribute `'http_error'`, the document says that I need to override `DbApiHook` method, but I don't know how.

And is there any solution for this issue? Appreciate for your help, guys.

Answer (score 3):

Use `BigQueryGetDataOperator`. Following is an example:

**Example**: ::

```
    get_data = BigQueryGetDataOperator(
        task_id='get_data_from_bq',
        dataset_id='test_dataset',
        table_id='Transaction_partitions',
        max_results='100',
        selected_fields='DATE',
        bigquery_conn_id='airflow-service-account'
    )
```

Official Documentation: https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/integration.html#bigquerygetdataoperator

Comment: Thanks for your answer! 
Em..., a little problem, i want to get the data by SQL query, but in this case, it only offers to select as fields.

Comment: You can use `BigQueryOperator` where you can put SQL and as a destination table specify a temporary table. Then use `BigQueryGetDataOperator` to get the data from that temp table.

Comment: Thanks mate, it's a good idea. One more thing need your help, how can i get the result which it says return in list, I thought the `get_data` is a list, but when i used `get_data[0][0]`, it told me `BigQueryGetDataOperator  object does not support indexing`. BTW, finally i need to convert the list to html, then pass it to `EmailOperator html_content`.

Comment: @Don Were you able to figure out how to extract the `list` from `get_data` variable returned?

Comment: Use `xcom` in the next task to get the result list